# How to get the selected Appointments in the Agenda components of JFXTRAS 2?

Tags: javafx-2, jfxtras

I'm having trouble on how can i get the selected appointments in the **agenda component** of [JFXTRAS 2](http://jfxtras.org/), any ideas on how can i get the selected appointments in the agenda component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [agenda](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs/blob/master/src/main/java/jfxtras/labs/scene/control/Agenda.java) component of the JFXTRAS 2 provide a `selectedAppointments` property.

So you could get the selected appointements,

```
Collection<Appointment> selectedAppointments = agenda.selectedAppointments();
```

listen to the property modifications,

```
agenda.selectedAppointments().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Appointment>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends Appointment> c) {
    }
});
```

bind the property to another one,

```
ObservableList<Appointment> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
Bindings.bindContent(observableList, agenda.selectedAppointments());
```

display the selected appointments in a `ListView`,

```
ListView<Appointment> listView = new ListView<Appointment>(agenda.selectedAppointments());
```

Comment: Hey bro thanks i owe you so much... can i ask a follow up question if you dont mind..

I'm trying to figure out on how can i detect the modification of appointments inside the agenda so i can update my database. I tried to use the editAppointmentCallbackProperty() method but nothings happen whenever i try to reposition the appointment or adjust the time sched.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Tabs, I'm thrilled to have helped you. For your problem on appointments modification, i think you should ask another question (i will +1 it).

Comment: based on the agenda source documentations there is no way of being inform of changes in the appointment, so i've decided to pursue another approach. Thanks to your help buddy, you really save my life haha.

Comment: If you use an Agenda.AppointmentImpl, you could handle modifications on the appointment since this implementation is based on javafx properties.

Comment: Look at this sample : https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-ensemble/blob/master/src/ensemble/samples/controls/AgendaSample1.java

Comment: As a late donation; the Agenda control assumes only an interface with setters and getters for appointment, because chances are high this class will be a non-JavaFX bean coming from a business layer. The idea is to provide your own implementation. If you do not want to do that, you can use (as gontard says) AppointmentImpl.

Comment: Hi @gontard. Would you mind looking at my questions on Agenda [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970420/how-to-get-appointment-details-when-an-appointmentpane-is-clicked-jfxtras) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681781/how-can-i-add-an-action-listener-onto-an-appointment-in-an-agenda-jfxtras-agend). I would really appreciate some help. Thank you.