# How to get appointment details when an AppointmentPane is clicked - JFXtras

Tags: java, javafx, jfxtras

I would like to print out an appointment's `summary` and `description` when a user clicks on a particular appointment retrieved from the database.

I'm trying to implement this with something like:

```
lAgenda.selectedAppointments().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Appointment>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Appointment> c) {
                System.out.println(c.toString());
            }
        });
```

I however, only get this:

```
com.sun.javafx.collections.NonIterableChange$GenericAddRemoveChange@1ef0f08
com.sun.javafx.collections.NonIterableChange$SimpleAddChange@1c3e48b
com.sun.javafx.collections.NonIterableChange$GenericAddRemoveChange@d57e70
com.sun.javafx.collections.NonIterableChange$SimpleAddChange@6022e2
com.sun.javafx.collections.NonIterableChange$GenericAddRemoveChange@54ddc1
```

How can I retrieve other items, like the ID of the row in the database row the appointment is being retrieved from? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the right property to be notified of the selection change.

You received a [ListChangeListener.Change](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html). As described in the javadoc, a change should be used in the this way :

```
 lAgenda.selectedAppointments().addListener(new ListChangeListener< Appointment >() {
     public void onChanged(Change<? extends Appointment> c) {
         while (c.next()) {
             if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                 for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i) {
                      //permutate
                 }
             } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                      //update item
             } else {
                 for (Appointment a : c.getRemoved()) {
                 }
                 for (Appointment a : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                     printAppointment(a);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

Now, you could print out [appointment](http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-agenda/index.html) summary and description :

```
private void printAppointment(Appointment a) {
    System.out(a.getSummary());
    System.out(a.getDescription());
}
```

If you need some specific properties on the appointment object (like a database id), you could create your appointment class by extending [AppointmentImpl](http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-agenda/jfxtras/scene/control/agenda/Agenda.AppointmentImpl.html) or by implementing [Appointment](http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-agenda/jfxtras/scene/control/agenda/Agenda.Appointment.html)